# addAttachment error in XML-RPC while using Java

Tags: java, xml-rpc, confluence

My Java code

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Vector;
import helma.xmlrpc.*;

public class test {

    private final static String server_url =
        "http://confluence.xyz.com:8080/rpc/xmlrpc";

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        try {

            XmlRpcClient server = new XmlRpcClient(server_url);

            Vector<Object> params = new Vector<Object>(2);
            params.add("user");
            params.add("pass");   

            String token = (String) server.execute("confluence2.login", params );
            System.out.println(token);

            Vector<Object> page = new Vector<Object>(3);
            page.add(token);
            page.add("~username");
            page.add("test_page");

            Object token1 = server.execute("confluence2.getPage", page );
            System.out.println(token1.hashCode());


            String fileName  = "C:/New folder/a.jpeg";
            String contentType = "image/jpeg";

            Vector<Object> attachment = new Vector<Object>(2);
            attachment.add("a.jpeg");
            attachment.add(contentType);
            System.out.println(attachment);

            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName));
            System.out.println(bytes);

            Vector<Object> attach = new Vector<Object>(4);
            attach.add(token);
            attach.add(token1.hashCode());
            attach.add(attachment);
            attach.add(bytes);
            System.out.println(attach);
            server.execute("confluence2.addAttachment", attach);

        }
         catch (Exception exception) {
            System.err.println("JavaClient: " + exception.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except on line where "addAttachment" is called,

error i get is

```
JavaClient: helma.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2104.addAttachment(java.lang.String, int, java.util.Vector, [B)
```

can anyone help me with any other library which i should be using. it seems helma.xmlrpc doesn't have addAttachment method

Answer (score 0):

I used org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient and not helma but the concepts should be the same.  It's not that "helma.xmlrpc doesn't have addAttachment method", it's just that you're calling addAttachment() with the wrong parameters. Try calling it with the proper parameters listed at https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/confluence-xml-rpc-and-soap-apis/remote-confluence-methods

> addAttachment(String token, long contentId, Attachment attachment, byte[] attachmentData)

so for apache xmlrpc, my partial code looks like:

```
    //add attachment to the page
    byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(FILE_TO_ATTACH));
    Map<String, String> attachInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    attachInfo.put("fileName", FILENAME);       
    attachInfo.put("contentType", CONTENT_TYPE);
    attachInfo.put("comment", COMMENT);

    //actually add it now
    client.execute("confluence1.addAttachment", new Object[]{token, PAGEID, attachInfo, bytes});
```